# How to install gem from gem server?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed My gem in my system and i also want my friend to install that gem from my source.I ran gem server command and tried to install it from friend system using my following command.

```
gem install gemname --source=http://myIP:8808
```

its not installed how to install it.

I am getting this error.
 **ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Not Found  404 (http://my_ip:8808/gems/my_gem-1.0.1.gem)**

Answer (score 0):

The host must start a gem server using

```
gem server
```

In a terminal

The client needs to add the url to its sources by inserting the following command

```
gem sources --add http://myIP:port_nr
```

After this, the client can download and install the gem by running

```
gem install gemname
```

I hope this helps

Comment: What i have done is same Instead of adding source i am using directly

Comment: Are you sure the client system can access the host his port? You need to forward the port if the other person is trying to download from another network

Comment: They are able to use and other gems are installing only the gems we created not working i checked gemspec also nothing seems to fishy. @Jasper van den Berg

Comment: The official gems are downloading because they are downloaded from an official mirror. Your gems probably are not downloading, because the ports are not forwarded correctly for the Hosts computer.

Comment: The officials gems i am doing in the same way. from my local  gems only. those got installed in my friends machine @Jasper

Comment: I solved the issue by installing my gem in separate folder. and i used that folder to run gem server.My gemserver will have only mygem.It is working